# ¿Es posible establecer dos idiomas en un sitio web?

Tags: html, web

Tengo una duda, ¿Es posible establecer dos idiomas en un sitio web?
Estoy desarrollando mi primera página web y me gustaría saber si es posible establecer dos idiomas (Inglés y español, para que esta pueda ser encontrada en los motores de búsqueda, en sus respectivos idiomas) y de ser así, ¿Cómo lo hago? Soy nuevo con HTML, así que disculpen si la respuesta es muy obvia.

```
<html lang="es">
```

Comment: Dale una leía a este enlace directamente de Google, puede que te ayude a aclarar varios puntos: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites

Incluso este articulo puede ayudarte si estas trabajando con PHP, o piensas usarlo más adelante: https://manuais.iessanclemente.net/index.php/Técnicas_y_consejos_para_crear_una_web_multi-idioma

Comment: Te recomiendo esta [documentación](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.es) que lo explica en español.